# Trouble importing android.support.v7.widget.CardView into Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library, material-design

I use Eclipse and I'm trying to create an application using the new `support-library-v7:21.+` from Lollipop.

- Created my new project
- imported in eclipse the `support-library-v7`
- changed in `project-properties` of support library the line: `target=android-21` with 21 target
- changed the target of my application in 21
- imported the library in my project
- clean all

After all i still got the invalid `R` declaration. I restarted Eclipse and then, after re-importing the library, seem went! I created a `Tolbar` and a `NavigationDrawer` as well without problem - it works.

Now, i would like to put a `CardView` in my `ListView` items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   >
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/codename"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/versione"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/link"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

well, first error: `No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardCornerRadius'`.
I tried to delete the attribute, restart the application but I get a the following crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Make sure you import `com.android.support:cardview-v7` too

Comment: Your parent LinearLayout needs layout_width and layout_height defined.

Comment: i fixed the layout but nothing..not works.. however..if i can do it, and i can put the card view.. the ripple effect onclick still works? or not?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Adding the library**

*Gradle*

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
```

*Eclipse*

[Using android.support.v7.widget.CardView in my project (Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449344/using-android-support-v7-widget-cardview-in-my-project-eclipse)

**Proper LinearLayout**

As the error said, a `LinearLayout` needs a `layout_width` and a `layout_heighth`. Always.

Comment: I use eclipse..no build.gradle... could be the problem?

Comment: Yes it still could. AppCompat and CardView are 2 differente libraries. See updated answer.

Comment: mmh restarting 3 times eclipse seems work..but the cardview is over all. i can't see the textviews..

Comment: Then change the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes.

Comment: ooook..then just one more question.. How can i still have the ripple effect onClick? Now disappears..

Comment: Ripple effect works only on API-21+ but should work here. If you have another issue, please post another (and more detailed) question about that ripple-related issue :)

Comment: @End.Game The "ripple effet" got ported pretty well by that library https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect ;)

Comment: @End.Game Did any of those helped?

Answer (score 0):

I have outlined the steps that worked for me as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700970/error-while-inflating-cardview). It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Tried adding Eclipse->properies->Android->Libraries->Add = CardView is not there.
Tried Eclipse->properies->JavaBuildPath->Libraries->Add Jars->(select from CardView->libs) did not work.

what worked:
cardview->project.properites, add android.library=true if missing.

Comment: Switch to Intellij or Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

We need to do both the things add android.support.v7.widget.CardView as a library project and also add + check it's jar file in java build path

Go to File -> Import -> Existing Android code into workspace --> Browse (Go to sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview) --> Click ok --> Click Finish

Right click on cardview project --> Properties --> Android(Left Pane) --> Enable isLibrary (tick the checkbox) --> Apply --> ok

Right click on your project --> Properties --> Android(Left pane) --> Add (under library) --> cardview --> apply --> ok

right click on your project again --> build path --> configure build path -->under libraries-->add jar-->expand cardview-->expand libs-->select android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar

under order and export-->check android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar-->click

Hope it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that you didn't import the `CardView` support project as your main project's library. To import `CardView` library, you need to do this:

1, first, import `CardView` support library into you Eclipse. The process should be like this:
`File`-->`Import`-->`Android`-->`Existing Android Code into Eclipse`-->`Browse`-->`.../sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview`-->`OK`-->`Finish`. Then you will see project of `android-support-v7-cardview` in your Eclipse in which all resource and jar is.

2, add `android-support-v7-cardview` into your main project as a library. Just like this: right-click your project-->`Properties`-->`Android`-->`Add`, and select `android-support-v7-cardview` into your project.

And then, rebuild your project. Errors about `CardView` in your project will be finished.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `build.gradle`  file (inside dependencies section) add the last versions for support library and `cardView` support library:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
}
```